# Pandas, Where column is null then replace with column A otherwise use column B

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a way to do the following logic(s) where condition without using numpy?

Currently I  do the below, and would like to try alternate methods.

First I combine two dataframes, then create the where condition logic.

```
final = pd.merge(combineQueryandBookFiltered,u1, left_on = ['positionId'], right_on = ['Position_ID'], how = 'outer')
final['pnlValue'] = np.where(final.Unif_MTM_USD.isnull(),final.pnlValue, final.Unif_MTM_USD) 
final['Unif_CUSIP'] = np.where(final.Unif_CUSIP.notnull(),final.cusip,final.Unif_CUSIP)    
final['Unif_ISIN'] = np.where(final.Unif_ISIN.notnull(),final.isin,final.Unif_ISIN)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For example for the first column:

```
final['pnlValue'] = final['Unif_MTM_USD'].combine_first(final['pnlValue'])
```

It takes the value of the caller series, and if that's `na`, then it uses the value in the other column

Comment: thanks, could you also help with the `notnull` example as well?